# Escape text in Bokeh Tools

Tags: bokeh

I have a Bokeh TapTool that opens a webpage

```
TapTool(callback=OpenURL(url='/mypage?key=@name'))
```

However, the text in the `name` column of my ColumnDataSource contains unsafe text.  I would like to escape this text.  Typically I use `tornado.escape.url_escape` for this.

Is there a way to apply a function like `url_escape` automatically or do I have to maintain a separate column of escaped text in my ColumnDataSource?

Answer (score 0):

As of `0.12.10` there is no functionality to escape field values in the client, nor are `CustomJSTransform` models yet applicable to `OpenURL`. My suggestion would be a `CustomJS` callback for the tap tool that does the escaping and opens the URL (a couple of lines of JS total).